# Manual upgrade to xcode iOS 7 layout ?

Tags: storyboard, xcode5

I have search but didnt find anything relevant to my question.
When I open my project in xcode 5 it asked me to upgrade. I skipped that moment. 
Now my project is basically for iOS 7 but in Xcode I still see older dark gradient bar and all that older stuff in storyboard. 
I tried to looked into this issue and googled around. but didn't find anything.
Can anyone help me to get my project upgrade storyboard to iOS 7 and xcode 5 format or know how to re-trigger the pop up below : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Xcode only changes two attributes during this upgrade offer in your Storyboard: enable Auto Layout and make the UI elements in Interface Builder appear as iOS 7. Here's how you can do those two things manually:

To enable Auto Layout, select your Storyboard file, then in the right hand pane select the File Inspector. At the top there's a tickbox labelled "Use Auto Layout". Just above it is a drop-down menu labelled "View as" which lets you switch between the iOS 6 (vintage) and the iOS 7 look.

[image]

Both Auto Layout and the way iOS 7 deals with view controllers will have implications on the way your apps work. It's probably wise to create a branch and do some experimenting to avoid unexpected surprises (because we've all been there).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the tip. I just needed to change open in 5.1 instead of 4.6 and everything is iOS7 style. Thanks for the quick tip.